# Can I change the Android startActivity() transition animation?

Tags: android, animation, fade, transition

I am starting an activity and would rather have a alpha fade-in for `startActivity()`, and a fade-out for the `finish()`. How can I go about this in the Android SDK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319465/how-to-change-all-the-activity-transitions-at-once-in-android-application/8319701#8319701

Comment: for slide transition
`startActivity(intent);`
 `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the same statement in which you execute finish(), execute your animation there too. Then, in the new activity, run another animation. See this code:

fadein.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:fillAfter="true">
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
            android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="500"/> //Time in milliseconds
</set>
```

In your finish-class

```
private void finishTask() {
    if("blabbla".equals("blablabla"){
        finish();
        runFadeInAnimation();
    }
}

private void runFadeInAnimation() {
    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    a.reset();
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourviewhere);
    ll.clearAnimation();
    ll.startAnimation(a);   
}
```

fadeout.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fillAfter="true">
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
         android:toAlpha="1.0"
         android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

In your new Activity-class you create a similiar method like the runFadeAnimation I wrote and then you run it in onCreate and don't forget to change the resources id to fadeout.

Comment: In addition, it may be better to use the default short animation time: ```android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"```

Comment: where is `runFadeAnimation()`

Comment: Guys, please be sure to see the real answer below this post.

Comment: what is blabbla ??!!

Answer (score 302):

Starting from API level 5 you can call overridePendingTransition immediately to specify an explicit transition animation:

```
startActivity();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.fade_in);
```

or

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: Add something like:   
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.fade_out);

 }

for adding back animations.

Comment: @RightHandedMonkey For adding back animations better override the finish(); method of the activity for case in which the activity ends by something else than the back button (e.g. a custom exit button...).

Answer (score 50):

See themes on android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.

Under [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) there should be `android:windowAnimationStyle` where you can see the declaration of the style in [styles.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml).

Example implementation:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">

    ...

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="WindowAnimationStyle">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Comment: http://www.maxters.net/2011/05/android-animation-between-activity-switching-using-theme/

Comment: Update links for themes.xml and styles.xml https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Best Solution .

Comment: How would you access `@android:anim/fade_in` from the java code?

Answer (score 21):

Use `overridePendingTransition`

```
startActivity();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

fadeout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 12):

For **fadeIn** and **fadeOut**, only add this after *super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)* in your new Activity class. You don't need to create something else (No XML, no anim folder, no extra function).

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in,R.anim.abc_fade_out);
```

Comment: overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

Answer (score 11):

If you always want to the same transition animation for the activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }
}
```

Comment: overridePendingTransition in deprecated, what is the updated variant?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply create a context and do something like below:-

```
private Context context = this;
```

And your animation:-

```
((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom,R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom);
```

You can use any animation you want.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to use the styles.xml solution, but it did not work for me with activities.
Turns out that instead of using `android:windowEnterAnimation` and `android:windowExitAnimation`, I need to use the activity animations like this:

```
<style name="ActivityAnimation.Vertical" parent="">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/exit_to_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/exit_to_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_from_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exit_to_bottom</item>
</style>
```

Which I then reference in my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ActivityAnimation.Vertical</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Also, for some reason this only worked from Android 8 and above.
I added the following code to my BaseActivity, to fix it for the API levels below:

```
override fun finish() {
    super.finish()
    setAnimationsFix()
}

/**
 * The activityCloseExitAnimation and activityCloseEnterAnimation properties do not work correctly when applied from the theme.
 * So in this fix, we retrieve them from the theme, and apply them.
 * @suppress Incorrect warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263900/1395437
 */
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
private fun setAnimationsFix() {
    // Retrieve the animations set in the theme applied to this activity in the manifest..
    var activityStyle = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.windowAnimationStyle))
    val windowAnimationStyleResId = activityStyle.getResourceId(0, 0)
    activityStyle.recycle()
    // Now retrieve the resource ids of the actual animations used in the animation style pointed to by
    // the window animation resource id.
    activityStyle = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(windowAnimationStyleResId, intArrayOf(android.R.attr.activityCloseEnterAnimation, android.R.attr.activityCloseExitAnimation))
    val activityCloseEnterAnimation = activityStyle.getResourceId(0, 0)
    val activityCloseExitAnimation = activityStyle.getResourceId(1, 0)
    activityStyle.recycle()
    overridePendingTransition(activityCloseEnterAnimation, activityCloseExitAnimation);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 // CREATE anim 

 // CREATE animation,animation2  xml // animation like fade out 

  Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Attend.class);
  Bundle bndlanimation1 =  ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), 
  R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
  startActivity(myIntent1, bndlanimation1);
```

Comment: It works for me, I'm using application as context.

Comment: chinese cat Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers are pretty correct, but some of them are deprecated such as when using **R.anim.hold** and some of them are just elaboratig the process.

So, you can use:

```java
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```