# android Can viewFlipper have activitys instead of layout

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have 3 Activity's that i like to put into a ViewFlipper configuration.

Right now i have big trouble going from activity 1-2-3 and back.

what is the best approach to do this?

Any help would be grate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ViewFlipper can not contain Activities. Your best bet would be to just use a custom Animation to perform the transition between each Activity: see [Can I change the Android startActivity() transition animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515264/can-i-change-the-android-startactivity-transition-animation) for a decent example. To go back call `finish()` in each Activity to end it.

EDIT: you want a TabActivity. You can hide the TabWidget and then swipe to switch between tabs.

Comment: thanks. I cannot finish any of them because the hole user experience is to switch between 3 activity's/screens doing som graphic manipulations in one and setting up values in another.

Comment: Ah. Well, that particular mechanic is really not something Android is good at: you have a stack of Activities. For what you want maybe you want a TabActivity, hide the TabWidget and then swipe to switch between tabs?

Comment: was thinking about that tabs. will the activity's stay alive during tab click?

Comment: Yep: all Activities in a TabActivity will retain state appropriately. You can then switch tabs programmatically as you so choose.

Comment: sound like just what i wanted. Im already half way btw. Had an old tabGroup example im fiddling with

Comment: This works grate thanks. Above my expectations. All three activity's are loaded and i use my buttons to walk back/forw. If anyone want to do the same look at this: http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Comment: @Femia. Im setting your answer as the right one. - Update your answer with "you want a TabActivity, hide the TabWidget and then swipe to switch between tabs"