# Custom fragment animation modal like default start activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I want to custom fragment animation which make it should look like default animation that `startActivity` does. 
It's some think like this:

[image]

I tried to search for `default activity animation` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214621/719212), but it doesn't work.
Does anyone know how to implement this kind of modal animation like above and put into `setCustomAnimations` of `FragmentManager`?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use **android support fragments** and **supportFragmentManager** and add like this

1. Addd these files in `res/anim` folder

**overshoot_slide_down**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

**overshoot_slide_up**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

2. Call this method in java file

   ```
   getSupportFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.overshoot_slide_up, 0,  0, R.anim.overshoot_slide_down)
   .add(container, fragment, tag).commit();
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks incorrectly. And the animation is very laggy

Comment: it isn't smooth, suddenly it appears. And animation doesn't like what I want

Comment: since its an overshoot interpolator in working which provides zig-zag fast motion. Just remove the interpolator from the animation xml file and increase the duration as per your requirement. Definitely will help you