# Make new activity appear behind old one during transition

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

What I'm trying to achieve is to override the start activity animation.

The animation should give the impression that the old activity is on top of the new activity, and then slides down and out of the screen to reveal the new activity. I've tried multiple ways such as using `overridePendingTransition(startAnim, exitAnim)`
But the problem is they both animate in the same timeline.  So `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.exit_slide_down);` You never see the exit animation because the new activity is on top. Can this be achieved using the framework?

[image]

Comment: I believe you can delay an animation, sorry for not being to more help though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the Android startActivity() transition animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515264/can-i-change-the-android-startactivity-transition-animation)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually, I've found a property called `android:zAdjustment` in the animation files.

If I put `android:zAdjustment="bottom"` in `hold.xml` (screen 2) and `android:zAdjustment="top"` in `push_down_out.xml` (screen 1) then I can get the desired effect.

This gets around the z order issue (I assumed it was an issue with animation timings so I was barking up the wrong tree).

John

Comment: Could you please include how your animation files looked like?

Comment: This turned out to be why my transition animation wasn't playing, either. As an added bonus, I only had to add the android:zAdjustment="top" to the exitanimation (the one I wanted playing on top), so you don't even need the "bottom" one.

Comment: @johncc can you please include xml files and source code? Thanks!

Comment: Looked everywhere for this answer. Great one!

Comment: I'm so glad I found this.  I thought I was going to have to use a clipping mask to get this effect.

Answer (score 30):

I've been trying to solve your solution in a sample project and I got it working with this code:

Call the animation with:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,R.anim.push_down_out);
```

R.anim.push_down_in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

R.anim.push_down_out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Comment: actually if you give different duration for each animation, it give really cool impression. For example for R.anim.push_down_in: `android:duration="900"` and for R.anim.push_down_out: `android:duration="1500"`

Answer (score 7):

The solution that works for me:

**R.anim.exit_slide_down**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:zAdjustment="top">  

    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" 
               android:toYDelta="100%p" 
               android:duration="600" />
</set>
```

...and then

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.exit_slide_down);
```