# activity animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I am developing an app in which I am using overridePendingTransition for animation on my activites, everything is fine but the problem is that I don't want to show animation which it to be started, means when I click on a button the my first activity must go down to the screen but the coming activity must be stable to its position, I have passed 0 in method as below

```
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.toptobottom, 0);
```

but my second activity fluctuates for a while can anybody tell me whats the problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question..

Comment: if you find any solution then please update here i'll also do the same

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is in your device, at least in Samsung i guess device animation should be turned on.

*Settings>>Display(GB)/Developer Option>> Animation/Window animation scale*

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a month I found the solution to this...

Check the exact same [question...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9294446/2219600)

I missed it from my translate:

```
android:fromYDelta="-100%p
```