# Android Animation slide up

Tags: android, animation, slide

How can I make slide up animation? I got this code thanks to user Romain Piel in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294446/android-animation-for-new-activity). But I can't figure how to make reverse effect. That Animation is for slide down but I want slide up. How can I do that? I am sorry if this is a bad question but animations are always confusing me.
I have tried with other codes too but it doesn't look nice.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,R.anim.push_down_out);
```

R.anim.push_down_in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="900"/>
</set>
```

R.anim.push_down_out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="900"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to adjust the from/to values. Look at it this way:

1. You still want the movements to end/start at y = 0 respectively.
2. You need to have then move in the *opposite* direction.

Therefore, it's just a matter of interchanging 100% and -100%. Easy.

*R.anim.push_up_in*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="900"/>
</set>
```

*R.anim.push_up_out*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="900"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Yeah I figured it later, I was replacing wrong values. Anyway thanks.

Comment: what does 100%p signifies here?

Comment: @alchemist "values from -100 to 100 ending with "%", indicating a percentage relative to itself; values from -100 to 100 ending in "%p", indicating a percentage relative to its parent; a float value with no suffix, indicating an absolute value" -- see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween

Comment: Could you give the code for slide down animation also. Thanks.