# How to change the way a new activity starts in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I don't like the look of how a new activity starts in android, the "fade in" and getting bigger untill it covers the screen.
Is there anyway to change the way?
Ideally, i want the activity just to appear all in one go

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294446/android-animation-for-new-activity

Comment: and this one more precisely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515264/can-i-change-the-android-startactivity-transition-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `overridePendingTransition()`method in Activity class to change the transition.Here are a good tutorial for this topic, [the link](http://ahdidou.com/blog/customize-android-activities-transition/#.U-ixX-OSwy0).
But I should mention the point that animation can be disable in phone setting and in this situation your animation transition wont show.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there could be an easier way.