# How can I start new activity as an expended circle from center

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I want to start a new activity from center of screen as an expended circle so the activity will be revealed as a circle like this.

[image: example]

Here is my current code
anim.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1" >
</scale>
```

animback.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

Calling the animation

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim,R.anim.animback);
```

The current code just zooms in the new activity but I want the activity to be revealed from center as a circle.

Comment: use animation, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294446/android-animation-for-new-activity and this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-animation-while-switching.html

Comment: This isn't the kind of animation I am looking for

Comment: Need more details...

Comment: I am trying to start an animation from center of the screen and expand to full screen, the animation should reveal the 2nd activity

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible with transition animations.

Maybe it is possible to achieve desired result in following way:

- Make a screenshot of Activity A before transition
- Transit to activity B without animation
- Overlay Activity A screenshot on Activity B
- Animate the overlay (apply custom drawing)

or

- Make an activity B transparent
- Transit to Activity B without animation
- Animate Activity B layout (apply custom drawing)

See also: [DevBytes: Custom Activity Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA)