# How to override onBackPressed() with overridePendingTransition() animation

Tags: android

`PlayPanel` activity should close in the form of a sliding panel to `MainActivity` when back button is pressed. However, there is no animation. `PlayPanel` activity simply closes normally.

`PlayPanel activity`

```
public class PlayPanel extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_panel);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(
             PlayPanel.this,
             MainActivity.class
             );

        startActivity(intent);

        overridePendingTransition(
             0, 
             R.anim.play_panel_close_background
             );
    }

    // onCreateOptionsMenu goes here

    // onOptionsItemSelected goes here
}
```

`play_panel_close_background.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="600"
        />
</set>
```

`the solution:`

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(
                0,
                R.anim.play_panel_close_outgoing_activity
        );
    }
```

Comment: So you're trying to have the `PlayPanel` slide out to the bottom, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)), the first argument to `overridePendingTransition` is the animation used for the incoming activity, ie. your `MainActivity`. And the second argument is used for the outgoing activity, ie. your `PlayPanel`.

**play_panel_close_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:zAdjustment="top">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="600"
        />
</set>
```

---

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    overridePendingTransition(
            0,
            R.anim.play_panel_close_background
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this solution works? I set the first argument to `overridePendingTransition` to zero, and set the other parameters, but the activity doesn't not slide. It still just disappears. By the way, `overridePendingTransition` does not work with `super.onBackPressed()` it only works with `finish()` and `startActivity()`

Comment: Do you still have a problem?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294446/make-new-activity-appear-behind-old-one-during-transition) is exactly my problem, but I cannot make the solution `android:zAdjustment=""` work. Can you make the solution with this attribute?

Comment: yeah, if you're using `startActivity`, then you need to add `android:zAdjustment="top"` to the exit transition so that it is on top of the new activity. With `super.onBackPressed()` or `finish()`, you don't need to, since there is no new activity.

Comment: Okay, this was the solution the entire time. Thanks!

Comment: How can I revert back the main activity without starting a new activity?

Comment: Your solution works perfectly WITHOUT `android:zAdjustment="top"`

Comment: Okay, I posted the solution at the bottom of my question thread. If you copy and paste it as your answer, I will check mark your solution.

Answer (score 14):

I implemented same animation before.
This code works. Please try it. Thanks.

DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_start_enter, R.anim.activity_scale_start_exit);
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_scale_finish_enter, R.anim.activity_slide_finish_exit);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

activity_slide_start_enter.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

activity_scale_start_exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9" />

</set>
```

activity_scale_finish_enter.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="0.9"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

activity_slide_finish_exit.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 4):

> This solution worked for me

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I cannot use "override pending transition" with "on back pressed"

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.play_panel_close_foreground, R.anim.play_panel_close_background);
        //PlayPanel.super.onBackPressed();

        Intent intent = new Intent(PlayPanel.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.play_panel_close_background);

    }
```

Comment: I see. Please try calling `overridePendingTransition()` after `onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Solution I have ever tried,**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_right_to_left_enter, R.anim.anim_right_to_left_exit);
}
```