# Error: Expected resource of type styleable [ResourceType] error

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

Take a look at this code snippet.
I am getting an error with the last line, because I am passing an 'index' instead of a resource. I thought it was a lint issue and tried to suppress it.
Then I noticed I am getting this error only when I building for release. It works fine when building for debug. I am totally clueless. Can anyone throw some light into what I am doing wrong.

```
//Get paddingLeft, paddingRight
        int[] attrsArray = new int[]{
                android.R.attr.paddingLeft,  // 0
                android.R.attr.paddingRight, // 1
        };
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
        if (ta == null) return;
        mPaddingLeft = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0);
        mPaddingRight = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(1/*error here*/, 0);
```

Comment: I don't know why this error is not shown for the first element in the array, for example. It is shown only for the following. If I create two arrays with one element each, there is no error. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 61):

I had the same issue when trying to build a signed apk.
Solved it by adding `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` to suppress the warning, now it works fine.

Comment: Or you can just use //noinspection ResourceType just before that line to avoid inspection only in that line of code

Answer (score 12):

```
@StyleableRes int index = 1;

mPaddingRight = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(index, 0);
```

Comment: This just moves the IDE warning to the row before (assigning to *index*)

Answer (score 4):

So the way I fixed this in Kotlin is the following: [(thanks to Simons post)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40414992/3625488)

```
companion object {
    private val attributes = intArrayOf(
            android.R.attr.paddingLeft,
            android.R.attr.paddingTop,
            android.R.attr.paddingBottom,
            android.R.attr.paddingRight)
}

init {
    val arr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attributes)

    @StyleableRes
    var i = 0

    val leftPadding = arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(i++, 0)
    val topPadding = arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(i++, 0)
    val rightPadding = arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(i++, 0)
    val bottomPadding = arr.getDimensionPixelOffset(i, 0)

    arr.recycle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.paddingLeft, outValue, true);
int paddingLeft = outValue.data;
```

Repeat the same for android.R.attr.paddingRight