# Close another activity from current one

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to accomplish this structure:

Activity A is showing. If some button is pressed then open activity B (without closing current instance of A). If I press a back button of B I want just to finish B so that I can see my old instance of A. But if in activity B I press another button, I want to close A and open C.

**How can I close activity A and start activity C when activity B is opened?**

**Explanation:** *When B is active the A **mustn't** be destroyed so that I could return to it. But if I want to open C then A **must** be destroyed, so that if I'd press back button of C I wouldn't see it anymore.*

*I already implemented the code that opens all of the activities by using startActivity() and finish() methods. All I need right now is an answer or suggetion of how could I rework my structure to accomplish my goal.*

**EDIT**

I think I've got an idea to use startActivtyForResult() when I want to open B, so that when I'm ready to open C I'd just let A do this with closing itself.

Comment: Why do you want to keep A open? What are you going to do about the OS randomly deciding to close A on its own while you are in B?

Comment: You should be implementing some logic in onPause() to persist any data required when returning to an active state in case the Activity is destroyed by the framework.

Comment: @cricket_007 It's all about animation. When I press back button I want to see B closing instead of opening A. Yes I could do it like startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class)); finish();. But if I do so I would see A openning. And also I want to keep data from A without passing them to B and then again passing them back to A.

Comment: You can override the transition

Comment: Or you could probably use Fragments instead.

Comment: @cricket_007 How can I do this?

Comment: Use different launch flags with starting your Activity - there is a whole bunch of them. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: If you mean Fragments, then somewhere in the docs, there any many pages on "effective navigation" and "fragment reuse" or "master-detail flow".  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: @cricket_007 no I meant transition. Fragments cannot be used in this particular case.

Comment: Here is the question I am referring to. I can't remember the code for "show no animation". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515264/can-i-change-the-android-startactivity-transition-animation You can poke around in the `android.R.anim` values to see if there are any that seem to mean "nothing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I've solved the problem:

Activity A:

```
//Start Activity B 
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, B.class), 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, C.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
//back button press:
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
finish();

//start Activity C button:
setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent());
finish();
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 6):

When you Press **Button C** go to the ActivityC you just need to pass addFlag method with intent as follows

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.butoonC){
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);  
  }
}
```

here **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** will remove all the activity from activity stack except **activity B** and **activity C**. So when u backpress from Activity B you Activity will not able to go back to Activity A.
I hope this work for u

Comment: It didn't work. When I pressed back button on C, A activity was shown.

Comment: if you are going from A to C then you press back press it will not work . if you go as per your question A to B and B to C.it will work for u .

Comment: I did as I said before. In Activity B I wrote this code to open C and when it was opened I pressed back button at C activity. My expected result was to see app closing but actual result was activity A. Look below I found a solution for this problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and worked for me

in Activity A when a button press to go to Activity B use this code :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               ActivityA.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

It is close Activity A and when back button pressed do not come back to this Activity.

Comment: Thanks for effort but your answer is not applicable for the question. Please double check what exactly was the question about and look at the accepted answer. Take care!