# Android - Two activities with the same bottom bar

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities with same bottom bar.
The problem is when i call to startActivity from Activity A to Activity B has some blink and is not looking so smooth.
for example what I want is like Activity with a container with two fragments and the activity has the bottom bar so this will not change the bottom bar.

I know Activity with Fragments can help me with that but is too complicated to change it on my project so is the last option for me.

I find one more option to do it with SharedElements transition but is supported only from api 21 (Lollipop).

[image]

This is my activities and I need the LinearLayout on bottom stay sticky when i change it to Activity B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up activity animations:

```
startActivity();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.fade_in);
```

Please, refer to this answer: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9291038/2470878)

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the defulat transtion between activites.
try this under yourProject/res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same instance you will have to use fragments.
If not you could just put that LinearLayout to both layout files. 
Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need create a layout and include ex. bottombar.xml in layout folder and create the layout.

```
 <include layout="@layout/bottombar"/>
```

if you dont want look delay in change you need use fragments.

To manage fragment, i recommended use [FragNav](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav)

With this library manage fragments its very easy, remove animation is not solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have made an Activity with two  fragments.
In Activity class ,I have write this code for commonBottomSheet  :-

```
BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_pannel_layout));
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetCallback);
```

In Activity xml file in Co-ordinator layout I have included below layout :-

```
<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_pannel"/>
```

In CommonBottomSheetFragment, you can create your layout .

And my xml file (bottom_sheet_pannel) for bottomSheet is like this :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_pannel_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="45dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grabber_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_slider_grabber"
        android:tint="@color/colorTint" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rf_common_details_fragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:name="com.fragment.CommonBottomSheetFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

you can change state of bottomSheet with below callBack :-

```
 private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        // do what you want on state change
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

    }
};
```